# CodeIgniter 4 Dynamic Routes

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm new to CI.
In my future project, we will have a menu structure like this:

```
Menu1
--Submenu1
--Submenu2
--[...]
Menu2
--Submenu3
--Submenu4
[...]
```

So, many menus, and each of them will have many submenus (many submenus will have a CRUD, or similar).
My problem is making the routes to all this pages, I would like to organize the Controllers inside folders (with the menu's name) and each submenu would be a Controller, like this:

```
/app/Controller/Menu1/Submenu1.php
/app/Controller/Menu1/Submenu2.php
/app/Controller/Menu2/Submenu1.php
etc...
```

And then my Views would be like this:

```
/app/Views/Menu1/Submenu1/index.php
/app/Views/Menu1/Submenu1/insert.php
etc...
```

But at the same time, I don't want to create one entry in the Routes.php file for each submenu, is there a way to create a route that simply takes the path URI and search in the folders for that exact values?

Comment: You should read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DanishAli I didn't get your point, I've already read the CI doc's and forums. I'm not asking for a pile of code, just how to route the controllers/views, and I introduced my problem before making the question.

Comment: There is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and its corresponding controller class/method. So i don't get your point ... just define a column url in your db where your menu is defined and thats it.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to use the (:segment) and (:any) to do this route, something like this: $routes->get('/(:segment)/(:segment)/(:any)', '$1/$2::$3');

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, bear in mind that you need to make code that is manageable. From the looks of it, your views and controllers will need to be a bit more streamlined otherwise it will become quite a lot to manage.

Therefore I think you would be better off doing a number of things:

1) Create a controller called MY_Controller.php in application/core and extend all controllers from it (that way you can centralise your methods)

2) User a per menu controller. So Controller = Menu1 or Menu2

3) Try and keep your views as re-usable as possible to avoid over complicating things

You should end up with something like this:

```
menu1/Submenu1 >> Controller (Menu1) >> function Submenu1

menu1/Submenu2 >> Controller (Menu1) >> function Submenu2
```

Bear in mind that with Codeigniter the following url will result in:

```
url: menu1/submenu1/param1/param2

Controller
function submenu1($param1,$param2)
```

So there is no need to get URI components as CI will route them automatically.

Comment: This is almost the answer I was looking for. My problem is that my project will have a lot of menus and submenus, so I wanted to divide them in sub-folders inside the Controllers folder. And also I don't want to write many "Actions"(functions) inside the same Controller (for example menu1 storing all functions of submenu1, submenu2, etc...). I tried this in the Routes file: " $routes->get('/menu1/submenu1', '\App\Controllers\Menu1\Submenu1::index'); ". But I get this error when accessing https://MY_IP/menu1/submenu1 - Controller or its method is not found: {0}::{1}